# Search for text and add text after

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that contains the following text format that occurs throughout:

```
5:43-64
```

I want to search and replace so that the text reads like so:

```
5:43-64 indicates:
```

Fortunately, the ***-*** only appears in this type of text. **The numbers change in each instance**. So I don´t think I have to worry about some complicated search pattern.  I can just search for the **-** character.

I want to then take whatever is after the the **-** and then save it as a variable then insert the text **indicates** afterward.  I need this to loop through the whole document making these changes at any occurrence of the **-**.

Here is the code that I have up to this point that kind of half works:

```
Sub placeWordAfterDash()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = "-"
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = False
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

If Selection.Find.Execute Then
    Dim selectedString As String
    Selection.Select
    selectedString = Selection.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text
    Selection.Text = "-" & selectedString & " indicates: "
End If

End Sub
```

This code only makes the change in one instance and also leaves me with:

```
5:43-64 indicates: 64
```

Which isn´t quite what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use vba to do this find-replace, you can do it with a simple wildcard find-replace.

press CTRL+H, find `(-<*>)`, Replace with `\1 indicates:` (make sure to check "Use Wildcards")

---

If you do want to use vba:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "(-<*>)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 indicates:"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: I am using this as part of a much larger macro which is written in VBA.  So I thank you for including the VBA code.